# install opencv-2.4-9 on centos 6.5 with cuda 5.5 support

Tags: linux, centos, opencv

I can't seem to install opencv 2.4.9 on centos 6.5 with cuda 5.5 support. This is my `cmake` output:

```
[root@cadejos-0 opencv]# cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/opencv -D WITH_CUDA=ON /opt/opencv-2.4.9/opencv/
    -- Detected version of GNU GCC: 44 (404)
    -- Looking for linux/videodev.h
    -- Looking for linux/videodev.h - found
    -- Looking for linux/videodev2.h
    -- Looking for linux/videodev2.h - found
    -- Looking for sys/videoio.h
    -- Looking for sys/videoio.h - not found
    -- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h
    -- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h - found
    -- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h
    -- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h - not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: No module named numpy.distutils
    -- Found apache ant 1.7.1: /usr/bin/ant
    -- 
    -- General configuration for OpenCV 2.4.8.2 =====================================
    --   Version control:               2.4.8.2-dirty
    -- 
    --   Platform:
    --     Host:                        Linux 2.6.32-358.18.1.el6.x86_64 x86_64
    --     CMake:                       2.6.4
    --     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
    --     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/gmake
    --     Configuration:               RELEASE
    -- 
    --   C/C++:
    --     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
    --     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 4.4.7)
    --     C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -ffunction-sections -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    --     C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -ffunction-sections -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    --     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/gcc
    --     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -ffunction-sections -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    --     C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -ffunction-sections -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    --     Linker flags (Release):
    --     Linker flags (Debug):
    --     Precompiled headers:         YES
    -- 
    --   OpenCV modules:
    --     To be built:                 core flann imgproc highgui features2d calib3d ml video legacy objdetect photo gpu ocl nonfree contrib stitching superres ts videostab
    --     Disabled:                    world
    --     Disabled by dependency:      -
    --     Unavailable:                 androidcamera dynamicuda java python
    -- 
    --   GUI: 
    --     QT:                          NO
    --     GTK+ 2.x:                    YES (ver 2.20.1)
    --     GThread :                    YES (ver 2.26.1)
    --     GtkGlExt:                    NO
    --     OpenGL support:              NO
    -- 
    --   Media I/O: 
    --     ZLib:                        /usr/lib64/libz.so (ver 1.2.3)
    --     JPEG:                        /usr/lib64/libjpeg.so (ver )
    --     PNG:                         /usr/lib64/libpng.so (ver 1.2.49)
    --     TIFF:                        /usr/lib64/libtiff.so (ver 42 - 3.9.4)
    --     JPEG 2000:                   /usr/lib64/libjasper.so (ver 1.900.1)
    --     OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
    -- 
    --   Video I/O:
    --     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
    --     DC1394 2.x:                  YES (ver 2.1.2)
    --     FFMPEG:                      YES
    --       codec:                     YES (ver 52.72.2)
    --       format:                    YES (ver 52.64.2)
    --       util:                      YES (ver 50.15.1)
    --       swscale:                   YES (ver 0.11.0)
    --       gentoo-style:              YES
    --     GStreamer:                   
    --       base:                      YES (ver 0.10.29)
    --       app:                       YES (ver 0.10.29)
    --       video:                     YES (ver 0.10.29)
    --     OpenNI:                      NO
    --     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
    --     PvAPI:                       NO
    --     GigEVisionSDK:               NO
    --     UniCap:                      NO
    --     UniCap ucil:                 NO
    --     V4L/V4L2:                    Using libv4l (ver 0.6.3)
    --     XIMEA:                       NO
    --     Xine:                        NO
    -- 
    --   Other third-party libraries:
    --     Use IPP:                     NO
    --     Use Eigen:                   NO
    --     Use TBB:                     NO
    --     Use OpenMP:                  NO
    --     Use GCD                      NO
    --     Use Concurrency              NO
    --     Use C=:                      NO
    --     Use Cuda:                    NO
    --     Use OpenCL:                  YES
    -- 
    --   OpenCL:
    --     Version:                     dynamic
    --     Include path:                /opt/opencv-2.4.9/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    --     Use AMD FFT:                 NO
    --     Use AMD BLAS:                NO
    -- 
    --   Python:
    --     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.6 (ver 2.6.6)
    -- 
    --   Java:
    --     ant:                         /usr/bin/ant (ver 1.7.1)
    --     JNI:                         /usr/lib/jvm/java/include /usr/lib/jvm/java/include/linux /usr/lib/jvm/java/include
    --     Java tests:                  NO
    -- 
    --   Documentation:
    --     Build Documentation:         NO
    --     Sphinx:                      NO
    --     PdfLaTeX compiler:           /usr/bin/pdflatex
    -- 
    --   Tests and samples:
    --     Tests:                       YES
    --     Performance tests:           YES
    --     C/C++ Examples:              NO
    -- 
    --   Install path:                  /opt/opencv
    -- 
    --   cvconfig.h is in:              /opt/opencv-2.4.9/opencv
    -- -----------------------------------------------------------------
    -- 
    WARNINGThe source directory is the same as binary directory. "make clean" may damage the source tree
    -- Configuring done
    -- Generating done
    -- Build files have been written to: /opt/opencv-2.4.9/opencv
```

I have cuda working:

```
[root@cadejos-0 opencv]# /usr/local/cuda-5.5/NVIDIA_CUDA-5.5_Samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery/deviceQuery
/usr/local/cuda-5.5/NVIDIA_CUDA-5.5_Samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery/deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Detected 2 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "Tesla M1060"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          5.5 / 5.5
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    1.3
  Total amount of global memory:                 4096 MBytes (4294770688 bytes)
  (30) Multiprocessors, (  8) CUDA Cores/MP:     240 CUDA Cores
  GPU Clock rate:                                1296 MHz (1.30 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             800 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              512-bit
  Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(8192), 2D=(65536, 32768), 3D=(2048, 2048, 2048)
  Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(8192), 512 layers
  Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(8192, 8192), 512 layers
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       16384 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 16384
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  1024
  Maximum number of threads per block:           512
  Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (512, 512, 64)
  Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (65535, 65535, 1)
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             256 bytes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 1 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     No
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support:                        Disabled
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      No
  Device PCI Bus ID / PCI location ID:           2 / 0
  Compute Mode:
     < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >

Device 1: "Tesla M1060"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          5.5 / 5.5
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    1.3
  Total amount of global memory:                 4096 MBytes (4294770688 bytes)
  (30) Multiprocessors, (  8) CUDA Cores/MP:     240 CUDA Cores
  GPU Clock rate:                                1296 MHz (1.30 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             800 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              512-bit
  Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(8192), 2D=(65536, 32768), 3D=(2048, 2048, 2048)
  Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(8192), 512 layers
  Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(8192, 8192), 512 layers
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       16384 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 16384
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  1024
  Maximum number of threads per block:           512
  Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (512, 512, 64)
  Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (65535, 65535, 1)
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             256 bytes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 1 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     No
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support:                        Disabled
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      No
  Device PCI Bus ID / PCI location ID:           3 / 0
  Compute Mode:
     < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 5.5, CUDA Runtime Version = 5.5, NumDevs = 2, Device0 = Tesla M1060, Device1 = Tesla M1060
Result = PASS
[root@cadejos-0 opencv]#
```

But somehow `cmake` doesn't find them. These are my variables:

```
[root@cadejos-0 opencv]# export
declare -x CVS_RSH="ssh"
declare -x G_BROKEN_FILENAMES="1"
declare -x HISTCONTROL="ignoredups"
declare -x HISTSIZE="1000"
declare -x HOME="/root"
declare -x HOSTNAME="cadejos-0"
declare -x LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
declare -x LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/lib64:"
declare -x LESSOPEN="|/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s"
declare -x LOADEDMODULES=""
declare -x LOGNAME="root"
declare -x LS_COLORS="rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=01;05;37;41:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=01;36:*.au=01;36:*.flac=01;36:*.mid=01;36:*.midi=01;36:*.mka=01;36:*.mp3=01;36:*.mpc=01;36:*.ogg=01;36:*.ra=01;36:*.wav=01;36:*.axa=01;36:*.oga=01;36:*.spx=01;36:*.xspf=01;36:"
declare -x MAIL="/var/spool/mail/root"
declare -x MODULEPATH="/usr/share/Modules/modulefiles:/etc/modulefiles"
declare -x MODULESHOME="/usr/share/Modules"
declare -x OLDPWD="/opt"
declare -x PATH="/usr/local/cuda-5.5/bin:/opt/mothur/:/opt/usearch/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin"
declare -x PWD="/opt/opencv"
declare -x SHELL="/bin/bash"
declare -x SHLVL="1"
declare -x SSH_CLIENT="10.0.0.1 48436 22"
declare -x SSH_CONNECTION="10.0.0.1 48436 10.0.0.10 22"
declare -x SSH_TTY="/dev/pts/0"
declare -x TERM="xterm"
declare -x USER="root"
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading cmake to version 2.8 fixed everything.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually specify CUDA toolkit location in cmake command line:

```
cmake -DCUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/cuda-5.5 <other options>
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for your reply.

Compiling with:
`cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/opencv -D WITH_CUDA=ON -D CUDA_SDK_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/cuda-5.5/ -D CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/cuda-5.5/ /opt/opencv-2.4.9/opencv/`

and i get:

**--     Use Cuda:                    NO**

Comment: Could you check all CUDA_ related variable in CMakeCache.txt file in opencv build directory, especially CUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE, CUDA_TOOLKIT_INCLUDE and CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY? Did the CMake find at least one of them?